# Grok filter with this line (fail2ban output)

Tags: apache, logstash, logstash-grok, fail2ban

I want to filter the following lines in logstash (this is output from fail2ban and the patterns that I have found so far do not really work)

```
2016-05-02 10:40:18,051 fail2ban.filter  [1122]: INFO   [bruteforce4] Found 192.168.1.3
2016-05-02 10:40:22,155 fail2ban.filter  [1122]: INFO    [symfony-token-request-ban]Found 192.168.1.2
2016-05-02 10:40:27,756 fail2ban.actions [1122]: NOTICE  [symfony-token-request-ban] Unban 192.168.1.1
```

Any help?

```
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}" ] 
match => [ "message", "^%{DATE} %{TIME}" ] 
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} [%{INT}] %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}" ] 
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{F2B_LEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}?" ] 
match => [ "message", "%{FAIL2BAN_BAN}" ]
```

Comment: SO is not a free codewriting service, please give an example of what you have tried so far and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I was following two different guides and I have tried the below:
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}" ]
match => [ "message", "^%{DATE} %{TIME}" ]
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} \[%{INT}\] %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}" ]
match => [ "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{F2B_LEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}?" ]
match => [ "message", "%{FAIL2BAN_BAN}" ] 
Ofcourse I have also added the pattern files

Comment: please add that to your original post

Comment: And the relevant custom patterns you are using